# How to change files from a specific TAG already in the repository?

Tags: git, github

In case I want to edit my **README.md** of a tag, however when I give the following commands **nothing happens:**

```
git checkout <tagname>
git add README.md
git commit -m "MESSAGE"
git push origin <tagname>
```

Comment: There's no smooth-n-easy way to put this: you need to spend more time with the Git docs.  This is utterly unsurprising behavior, the tag still points where it always pointed, you made a new commit with no ref pointing to it, it's a work-in-progress without even a name yet, just a commit id.

Answer (score 2):

A tag-name is meant to be a specific name for *one specific commit*, i.e., one raw hash ID.

When you modify the `README.md` file (or add a new one) and make a new commit, that's ... a *new* commit.  It has a different hash ID.  You should make a *new* tag, if you want to use a tag at all here, to remember the new commit's hash ID:

```
git checkout v1.2                   # goes into detached HEAD mode
... modify files, commit them ...
git tag -a v1.3                     # make new tag `v1.3`

git push origin v1.3
```

It *is* possible to move a tag to a new commit, but then you will have to use `git push -f` and others who are cloning and making use of your `origin` repository may choose not to update *their* tag.

This kind of thing—having a name for the *latest* commit—is precisely what branch names are for.  If, instead of a tag like `v1.2`, you did:

```
git checkout foo                # gets on branch foo
... modify files, commit them ...
git commit                      # makes new commit, updates foo to refer to it
git push origin foo
```

everyone would be unsurprised by the sequence of events.